# I want to check HTML element, That, If an element exist this exampleClass via element ID JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I am new in front-end development, and want to know some front-end element's functionality.
I want to check HTML element, That, If an element exist this exampleClass via element's ID JS/JQuery
Example:

```
<div class="exampleClass" id="myElement"></div>
```

I want to select the above example via its id,

Comment: Did you remember to search before posting? Its a pretty standard thing to do, for example, [here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727781/faster-way-to-select-an-element-with-a-given-id) on Stack Overflow already, one among the many others.

Answer (score 0):

var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
console.log(element);